# Is it possible to use one WAN for upload only and one WAN for download only?

Tags: routing, router

I have a pretty poor DSL connection at my office, especially regarding upload.

I was wondering if it exists some solutions to use a 4G WAN for upload only and my DSL for regular download.

By doing so, I expect to get the better of my data volume limited 4G access.

For example, my Dropbox will use the 4G wan to upload my new files and the regular DSL to download existing files or files uploaded by collaborators.

Is it technically possible ? Which solutions can you advices ?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This exists.

Any reasonable multi-WAN router can do this, but a purpose-built link-balancer is a good choice, too. See http://elfiq.com

https://serverfault.com/questions/750184/best-load-balance-hardware/750187#750187

https://serverfault.com/questions/507319/using-dual-isp-and-static-ip/507359#507359

https://serverfault.com/questions/63788/best-solution-for-multi-wan-failover-inside-out/164782#164782

https://serverfault.com/questions/94123/link-aggregation-with-dsl-and-ethernet-and-different-isps/164785#164785

https://serverfault.com/questions/543639/can-i-balance-load-between-4-adsl-links/543643#543643

---

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that these are not making routing decisions based on upload/download. Unless there's some sort of magic involved, they're making policy-based routing decisions based on the target (or source) IP address.

Comment: The Elfiq can make that decision.